# Qt Programming:Installer not able to create shortcut in start menu in Windows 7

Tags: qt

I am creating an installer to deploy some application .and I am getting following problems

1. I want all applications shortcut get created in start menu  under  a common name like MS Office:

****Start MENU->CMKIT->gcompris

```
                  ->open office


                  ->Scratch****
```

but I am not able to do this.

2. A pop up should be launched at the end of installation,which has buttons for each application and it will start respective application when user clicks on button**.I tried a lot but not got solution.**

Its very critical for me,please help me.I am also ready to pay for this but give me solution for these.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that I can't help you with your exact problem, but if this is so critical you should really be using a tried and tested installer system, such as InstallShield or NSIS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not Qt-related. The solution to your problem depends on the installer framework you use, so you should mention it...

Comment: @Frank -Thanks for look into problem!!
It has common framework like other installer has.
This installer consist six Wizard pages

.
 1.Welcome page
 
2. License Page 

3.Installation type:(a) custom type -choose applications to install 
                    (b)  Default type-Install all application

4.Location page-User can choose installation location manually

5.Installation-Shows installation progress

6.Finish page.

please help me to find out the solution.